# Проверка на Null бинов спринга

Tags: java, spring

Команда разработчиков спринга рекомендует проверять при инъекции бины на null, почему они сами не проверяют на каком то этапе к примеру в postprocessor. Ведь это не все будут проверять, кому нужен bean в виде Null а если и надо тогда оставить настройку для того чтобы разрешать, и к тому же будет меньше кода

Comment: По этому и не проверяют, потому-что, кому-то, нужен будет `null`.

Comment: @and кому нужен null и почему нельзя было просто оставить отдельную настройку для такого очень редкого кем то хотения

Comment: А где они это советуют? Autowired если нет бина выдаст exception, если прогер сам в @Bean впилит null. Это может иметь место только если вы будете класс использовать без спринга, да и то, там если вы Autowired поставили над конструктором, а не над полями, то всё будет ок.

Comment: даже IDEA подсказывает, лучше автовайрить через конструктор и проверять на null, Если бин null при инжекте не выдаст exception, можете сами проверить.